# Check if JSON has only one string or is an array

Tags: javascript, json

From there [How to check whether the given object is object or Array in JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817315/how-to-check-whether-the-given-object-is-object-or-array-in-json-string) i've found useful to compare if JSON object is array or object

```
if (json instanceof Array) {
    // get JSON array
} else {
    // get JSON object
}
```

**Problem** I have a validator login form and i get messages like:

array('password' => array('isEmpty' => 'Value is required and can't be empty'));

However there is messages like

'Email or password is invalid' , that isn't an array.

**Question** I need something like this in JavaScript file

```
if(json hasOnlyOneString)
{
    //do something
} else { || } if(json instaceof Array){
    // do another stuff
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to supply the actual JSON sent over the network. It looks like your "array" is actually a non-array object.

Comment: Here is what appears when i console log error messages https://imageshack.us/i/iduC09Dap

Comment: note, `array('password' => array('isEmpty' => 'Value is required and can't be empty'))` will not be an instance of `Array` in JavaScript.. it also isn't a string, it will simply be an object with a property that contains another object with a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you sometimes get a string when you expect an array or an object. You can check it like this:

```
var obj = {
 "str": "I am a string",
 "arr": ["I am an array"]
};

obj.str instanceof Array; // -> false
obj.arr instanceof Array; // -> true
typeof obj; // -> object
typeof obj.arr; // -> object (uh-oh! eliminate this possibility by first checking to see if it's an array)

if (obj.str instanceof Array) {
  console.log('do array stuff');
} else {
  if (typeof obj.str === "object") {
    console.log('do object stuff');
  } else {
    console.log('do non-array, non-object, probably string stuff');
  }
}
```

Comment: this is what i get https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/385x127q90/742/Hsmdum.png. Both error messages are considered arrays.