# Issue in converting String to JSONArray/JSONObject

Tags: java, org.json

I have to check whether the given value is JSONObject or not....
example input :

```
Object obj = "{} testing"
```

i am checking with below code:

```
public boolean isJSONValid(Object obj) {
 try {
   new JSONObject(obj);
 } catch(JSONException e) {
   return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

but for above input it is giving true, am using org.json jar file.

Comment: I think this question is quite similar to this one: [How to check if a string is a valid JSON string in JavaScript without using Try/Catch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710204/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-json-string-in-javascript-without-using-try). You might use the regular expression suggested or also `JSON.parse(str);` alternative with try/catch

Comment: Thank you, i will try using regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

To check if an object is a JSONObject use `instanceof`.

```
if(obj instanceof JSONObject){
  //your code here
}
```

---

You can test if a String is valid JSON using:
[How to check whether a given string is valid JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174898/how-to-check-whether-a-given-string-is-valid-json-in-java) 
But I'm assuming you already found that, looking at the similar code.

---

**EDIT**

This function returns false when given `obj = "{} testing";`

```
public boolean isJSONObject(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof JSONObject){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I've added a piece of code that does in fact return the correct value for your problem using `instanceof`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you print the "new JSONOBJECT(obj)" to string after you create it? I would think it is using reflection to convert that standard object to a JSON object when you are passing it to the constructor. Reference the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817315/how-to-check-whether-the-given-object-is-object-or-array-in-json-string). It shows how to check if an object is an instance of a JSONObject.